# Can i create custom android ambient application?

Tags: android, ambient

I didn't managed to find anything on this, can i create my custom android application that's going to work in ambient mode, so the phone is using only the pixels that are needed (like letters) and not the whole screen ? Something like this: [Ambient display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF9Ee.jpg)

Comment: I guess it is a pretty device specific feature (looks a bit like an eInk screen to me) Wouldn't setting the background color to black and the foreground color to white have the same effect?

Comment: If you just set the background to black then the pixels will be active but black. I want only the pixels for the letters to be active so i can save battery.

Comment: I don't know if this feature is available on all OS 5+ devices.

Comment: The feature being available is not a problem, my phone has it i want to make app for personal use @AVEbrahimi